# Algorithms to obtain all highest weight paths in directed acyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I want to identify all of the highest-weight paths between all of the start and end nodes of a directed acyclic graph with positive weights. Calculating the scores of all possible paths is computationally prohibitive for my dataset. I know that Dijkstra's algorithm can find the optimal path between two nodes but it seems like I would have to run it as many times as I have combinations of start and end nodes.

I may have missed something about Dijkstra's algorithm, or I may have been unable to find another, more appropriate one. So my question is what are the different algorithms that can find the highest-weight paths between all start and end nodes, simultaneously if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 2):

It is surely not be the best option but you could always reverse you weight ($w=-w$), and use [Bellman-Ford](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/bellman-ford-algorithm) algorithm to determine the minimum-weight path. You have no cycles therefore the algorithm should work.

Comment: You can use Dijkstra's algorithm. Also, you can just check maximum weight instead of reversing weights and proof of correctness will be same.

Comment: These algorithms give you the highest weight paths between two vertices, right? So if I want all pairs of start and end vertices I have to run them multiple times? Or do they have different forms?